# Issue with binding dropdown options using ko.computed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a template which has a dropdown (using custom library) as below:

```
<select id="selectmyField" data-bind="libraryComponent: 
  { component: 'libSelect', 
    options: myViewModel.myFieldOpts, 
    value: myViewModel.myFieldSelected }">
</select>
```

I am trying to bind the dropdown options using ko.computed and based on the response I get from API call. Below is the code:

```
self.myFieldOpts = ko.computed(function(){
    var myFieldData = data.apiResponseData,
        myFieldArray = [],
        someOtherField = self.someOtherFieldSelected();
    myFieldArray.push({
        value: "any",
        label: "Any"
    });
    // some logic to push apiResponseData to myFieldArray
    return myFieldArray; //can see this array getting populated correctly
}, self);
```

I have debugged and can see the myFieldArray with value/label properties. 
But the dropdown options are not getting displayed on UI.

Am I losing some context while doing ko.computed?

Comment: What is the `libraryComponent` binding? Looks like it's probably an issue in that somewhere?

Comment: It's mainly a component for UI related stuff...am sure there is no issue with that though...

Comment: ok.  Your `computed` looks fine on the face of it

Comment: so no issue with the context...it seems to you ?

Comment: Not from what you've shown - I've used `computed`s quite a lot in similar ways, returning both plain arrays and `observableArray`s - usually bind fine

Comment: You don't show all your code, but it's likely you should remove the `myViewModel.` prefix on the bindings in your HTML.

Comment: In which observable does your computed depend? If it doesn't dependn on other observables, that's the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you read their [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

> Computed observables  are functions that are dependent on one or more other observables, and will automatically update whenever any of these dependencies change.

You better to use `observableArray` instead of `computed` observable. I suppose your code be better like this

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   var self = this;
   self.selectedOpt = ko.observable("");
   self.options = ko.observableArray([]);

   self.initOptions = function () {
      // you code to grab data from server
      var myFieldData = data.apiResponseData,
          myFieldArray = [],
          someOtherField = self.someOtherFieldSelected();

      self.options.push({ value: "any", label: "Any" });
   };
};
var vm = new ViewModel();

$(document).ready(function() {
  vm.initOptions();
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectmyField" data-bind="options: options, value: selectedOpt">
</select>
```

Comment: I want to update based on 2 things; a. API success & b. change in someOtherField (other observable)

Not sure if using observableArray would work? If yes, could u pls elaborate on how i can make observableArray work considering the above 2 thing

Comment: @testndtv You'd have to subscribe to the other observable and write a function to update your observable array.  You're probably better off sticking with the computed, since you'd need the function anyway, and it has an implicit subscribe to the observable built in.

Comment: yes...that is what my thinking was...but not sure why the computed returned result (array) is not getting binded/displayed to the UI ?